# Jquery Checkbox fade in fade-out is not working. but working in fiddle

Tags: jquery

I tried a small code snippet to hide form div tag and fade in when a checkbox is clicked.

Please have a look at the code

```
$('checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($('[id=vfb-i-would-like-samples-in-24-1]').attr("checked"))
    {
        alert("test");
        $('.vfb-timber-34').fadeIn();
        return;
    }
   $('.vfb-timber-34').fadeOut();
});
```

But When I use it in the live site its not working. Can someone help me.

Here is the fiddle url
http://jsfiddle.net/addyosmani/ND428/

Here is my site url 
http://conceptclick.webande-commercesolutions.com/?page_id=2238

When you go to "I would like samples in" on bottom. there is 3 check-boxes Timber Aluminum and Echo Panel.. When a person clicks Timber that div should fade in.

Comment: which checkboxes want to be animated in your site?, every one of them ?

Comment: So you're going to make us guess where on that page to find the code that you're supposedly having trouble with?

Comment: I am sorry. When you go to "I would like samples in" on bottom. there is 3 checkboxes Timber Aluminum and Echo PAnel.. When a person clicks Timber that div should fade in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('checkbox')` will find `<checkbox>` elements.  There's no such thing, so nothing's getting the event handler attached to it.

Try `$('.checkbox')` instead.  And the `ready` thing mentioned by Paul wouldn't hurt either.  :)

Comment: Oh, didn't even notice that he forgot the dot.  +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my problem. Thanks again.. Stackoverflow rocks always

Answer (score 1):

Your `$('checkbox').change(function () {` is never getting activated.  You're probably calling it before the checkboxes are on the screen.  Try wrapping it in a

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
});
```

block.

By the way, this was really easy to determine by putting a breakpoint on the first line of the function in Firebug and clicking the checkboxes.  Debugging with Firebug is a really useful skill for Javascript developers - you should learn how.

Comment: I placed it on the bottom of the page. But still no luck :(

Comment: Placing it on the bottom of the page is not the equivalent of using `document ready`.  But @cHao has the real problem.